# Can I reduce ibdata1 file size by converting table to MyISam?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have a table called `path`. It takes up about 99% of a 13G ibdata1. It was previously an `INNODB` table, but I converted it to `MYISAM`.

If I run optimize table on the new `path` table, will it free up my ibdata1 file? Or does this never reduce in size and I need to delete it and re-import a fresh database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Dropping the InnoDB table will free up space *within* the InnoDB tablespace (`ibdata1` file), but it will *not* shrink the `ibdata1` file.

The exception is that if the table was created while the server `innodb_file_per_table` variable was set, then the table will be in its own separate InnoDB tablespace (datafile), and when the table is dropped, the space used by the table *will* be released.

See: [**14.3.3. Using Per-Table Tablespaces**  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no (better explanation above). What I had to do was this:

```
1) Dump the database
2) Stop mysql
3) Delete the `ibdata1` file and two log files.
4) Restart mysql
5) Import the sql dump.
```

This will get you back to the default `ibdata1` file size. Then you can either 1) change the engine of the table to myisam if there are no integrity constraints on the table (which is what I did) or 2) set `innodb_file_per_table=ON`, if keeping the innodb table.